# Write $W$ in terms of $U$ and $V$ where $\phi_W=\phi_U+\phi_V$ and $\tanh(i)=\phi_i$ for all $i$.

Tags: hyperbolic-functions, inverse-function

Write $W$ in terms of $U$ and $V$ where $\phi_W=\phi_U+\phi_V$ and $\tanh(\phi_i)=i$ for all $i$, using the fact that
$$\tanh^{-1}(x)=\frac{1}{2}ln\frac{1+x}{1-x}$$

---

Where I'm at:
$$\tanh(\phi_i)=i$$
$$\tanh^{-1}(i)=\phi_i$$

$$...$$

$$W$$
$$=\tanh(\phi_W)$$
$$=\tanh(\phi_U+\phi_V)$$
$$=\tanh(\tanh^{-1}(U)+\tanh^{-1}(V))$$
$$=\tanh(\frac{1}{2}ln\frac{1+U}{1-U}+\frac{1}{2}ln\frac{1+V}{1-V})$$
$$=\tanh(\frac{1}{2}ln\frac{(1+U)(1+V)}{(1-U)(1-V)})$$
$$=\tanh(\frac{1}{2}ln\frac{1+U+V+UV}{1-U-V+UV})$$

If only the denominator was equal to $1-U-V-UV$ We could let $x=U+V+UV$ in $\tanh^{-1}(x)=\frac{1}{2}ln\frac{1+x}{1-x}$.

Answer (score 0):

You got as far as
\begin{eqnarray*}
=\tanh(\frac{1}{2}ln\frac{1+U+V+UV}{1-U-V+UV})
\end{eqnarray*}
It can be rewriten as 
\begin{eqnarray*}
=\tanh(\frac{1}{2}ln\frac{1+UV+ (U+V)}{1+UV-(U+V)}).
\end{eqnarray*}
Now divide top & bottom of the fraction by $\color{blue}{1+UV}$
\begin{eqnarray*}
=\tanh\left(\frac{1}{2}ln\frac{1+ \frac{U+V}{1+UV}}{1-\frac{U+V}{1+UV}}\right)=\color{red}{\frac{U+V}{1+UV}}.
\end{eqnarray*}